# How to load .mat files onto Matlab? Basically what's wrong with my code?

Tags: matlab

For this project we have been given code, and will be changing some inputs and assumptions. Thus, I already possess the original codes, but just changing all the creator's file paths to match my own computer is yielding me a lot of trouble. The following, and many variations of, continually yield errors.

`load \Users\myname\Library\Documents\...`

The error is

```
Error using load
```

'Unable to read file
\Users\myname\Library\Documents...'. 
No such file or directory.

My files are stored in my Documents.  Another person in my group on windows has used

```
load C:\Users\hisname\Desktop\...
```

Is there something I'm missing in my line, similar to the C drive but on Mac?  Is my code just completely wrong, I'm able to load files in R quite easily, but Matlab is posing a huge hurdle.  I have no experience with Matlab and have been asked simply to run this code.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the error? What is the context where the code is?

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: Please show exactly what you did. `...` tells MATLAB that the command continues on the next line. Also, I could not get MATLAB to produce that error message that you show, where the file name ends in '...'. You must have changed the exact error message text.

Comment: The ... was just meant to signify the document name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac, path components are separated by `/`, not `\`. Thus, you should type

```
load /Users/myname/Documents/filename.mat
```

You can use the location bar at the top of the command window to change to the directory where your file is located, and then you can type

```
load filename
```

to load `filename.mat`.

Also, are you sure you have a Documents directory under Library? Why?

Answer (score 0):

To run code from a file called "my_file.m", than just open your Matlab and type `run my_file.m`. This will run your script in the Command Window.
The load function is used, if you want to load a .mat file. These are normally files, where variables from your workspace are stored.

Comment: For this project we were tasked with running the code given to us, as we will be changing assumptions and inputs.  I have a .m file open, and to run it, there are .mat files it loads in the beginning as variables.  My main problem is, what is the flaw in my code I'm overlooking because as I am changing the file paths, it won't open from my computer.